# 302 redirects do not work in a service worker built with Google Workbox

Tags: javascript, service-worker, progressive-web-apps, workbox

For having the "add tome homescreen" alert displayed, I want to integrate a service-worker and an offline capability of the application: When the user is offline, the app should simply display a special offline HTML file.

My service-worker looks like this:

```js
importScripts('https://storage.googleapis.com/workbox-cdn/releases/3.1.0/workbox-sw.js');

const CACHE_VERSION = 1;

workbox.core.setCacheNameDetails({
  prefix: 'app',
  suffix: 'v' + CACHE_VERSION
});

workbox.routing.registerRoute(
    '/offline-page.html',
    workbox.strategies.networkFirst({
        networkTimeoutSeconds: 2,
        cacheableResponse: { statuses: [0, 200] },
    })
)

workbox.routing.registerRoute(
    ({ event }) => event.request.mode === 'navigate',
    ({ url }) =>
        fetch(url.href, { credentials: 'include', redirect: 'follow', }).catch(() => caches.match('/offline-page.html'))
)
```

But as soon as my application returns a 302 redirect (e.g. after login oder logout), I get the following warning message in the console:

> The FetchEvent for "https://app.com" resulted in a network error response: a redirected response was used for a request whose redirect mode is not "follow".

and Google Chrome diplays an error page (ERR_FAILED) saying that the website can't be reached.

Does anyone have an idea how to fix this?

Answer (score 2):

You can adapt the "[Provide a fallback response to a route](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/workbox/guides/advanced-recipes#provide_a_fallback_response_to_a_route)" recipe in the docs to accommodate your particular restrictions.

There are a couple of different options for accomplishing this, but the cleanest would be to create your own [network-only strategy](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/workbox/reference-docs/latest/workbox.strategies#networkonly) (to mimic the `fetch()` that you're using in your example), chain `.catch()` to the end of it, and then use that as the `handler` when constructing a [`NavigationRoute`](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/workbox/reference-docs/latest/workbox.routing.NavigationRoute).

That will give you a `Route` that you could then pass to [`workbox.routing.registerRoute()`](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/workbox/reference-docs/latest/workbox.routing#.registerRoute).

```
// You're responsible for either precaching or
// explicitly adding OFFLINE_HTML to one of the caches.
const OFFLINE_HTML = '/offline-page.html';
const networkOnly = workbox.strategies.networkOnly();
const networkOnlyWithFallback = networkOnly().catch(() => caches.match(OFFLINE_HTML));
const route = new workbox.routing.NavigationRoute(networkOnlyWithFallback);
workbox.routing.registerRoute(route);
```

Comment: If I use your code, I get the following error: `Uncaught TypeError: networkOnly.catch is not a function`. Also right now I'm doing exactly what you posted here: [GitHub Issue](https://github.com/GoogleChrome/workbox/issues/796). It's just that 302 redirects are not processed correctly by my service-worker...

Answer (score 1):

This seems to do the trick:

```
const FALLBACK_URL = '/';

const networkOnly = workbox.strategies.networkOnly();

const route = new workbox.routing.NavigationRoute(({event}) => {
  return networkOnly.handle({event})
    .catch(() => caches.match(FALLBACK_URL));
});

workbox.routing.registerRoute(route);
```

Comment: For Workbox version 4.3.1, use:
```const FALLBACK_URL = workbox.precaching.getCacheKeyForURL('/offline.html');

workbox.routing.registerRoute(
    new workbox.routing.NavigationRoute(({event}) => {
        return (new workbox.strategies.NetworkOnly()).handle({event})
            .catch(() => caches.match(FALLBACK_URL));
    })
);
```